# Checking if PWD contains directory name

Tags: bash, shell

I want to find out if the PWD contains a certain directory name in it, it should be able to test it being anywhere in the output.

For example I have structure paths like `public/bower_components/name/` and also have paths which are just `public`.

I want to test because the contents of the folder `name` move into the public folder and the `bower_components` folder is removed.

Thanks

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can use BASH regex for this:

```
[[ "$PWD" =~ somedir ]] && echo "PWD has somedir"
```

OR using shell glob:

```
[[ "$PWD" == *somedir* ]] && echo "PWD has somedir"
```

Comment: The `==` doesn't get you anything over `=` in a shell pattern-matching expression, but it does lose you portability and clarity over arithmetic expressions. May as well make it `=`.

Comment: `[[` is already not portable, so I would not argue against `==` inside it. `[ ... == ... ]`, while accepted by `bash`, is another matter.

Comment: Thanks, this answer was helpful!

Answer (score 9):

You can use `case`:

```
case "$PWD" in
    */somedir/*) …;;
    *) ;; # default case
esac
```

You can use `[[`:

```
if [[ "$PWD" = */somedir/* ]]; then …
```

You can use regex:

```
if [[ "$PWD" =~ somedir ]]; then …
```

and there are more ways, to boot!